# How can I remove window.open() if the link in the () is blank?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, window.open

```
<span id="[LINK1]"><a href="link1" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('[LINK2]'); window.open('[LINK3]');">text</a></span>
```

Whenever link 2 or 3 is blank, the code will open a blank window, so I was wondering what jquery I can add to check if the parenthesis in the windows.open is blank, and if it blank, to remove that window.open() attribute.

Edit: to clarify, the link's are generated from a token used in a DNN module template editor. For example, there is a form where I enter a link in the field link1, and then I use the token [LINK1], the link in that field will be used instead.

Thank you

Comment: Check it in a function and call the function `onclick`

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function and do the checking in it.

```
<a href="link1" onclick="open_links(link2, link3)">text</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function open_links(link2, link3) {
        if (link2 != '')
            window.open('link2');
        if (link3 != '')
            window.open('link3');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! In place of link1, 2, and 3, I am using tokens, which gets a link from a form. I tried replacing all the link values with the token names, but it only opened the page from the first link in the href. I was wondering if I had to do something different in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can get the urls from any external source. For the following example, I've used an array.

```
    <span id="link"><a href="link1" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('link2'); window.open('link3');">text</a></span>
<br>
    Old HTML :
    <div id="old"></div>
    <br>
New HTML: 
    <br>
<div id="new"></div>

var newLinks = "";
var linkArray = new Array();
linkArray.push("http://www.google.com");
linkArray.push("http://www.msn.com");
linkArray.push("");

$.each(linkArray,function(i)
{ 
    if(linkArray[i])
    newLinks += "window.open('" + linkArray[i] + "');"; 
});

$("#old").text($("span").html());

$("span a").attr('onclick', newLinks);

$("#new").text($("span").html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ukdny1gb/2/